# Is there a way to call Java class with main() from JSP and print the value in the console or JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I have a doubt:

1. Is it possible to call a Java class with main() in JSP and print the value in console or  JSP page (without use of a Servlet class)?
2. Similarly print the value in JSP page from Java class with main() (without use of a Servlet class)?

*please need some explanation.*

Comment: What do you mean by "without use of a Servlet class"? JSP files are translated to servlets so it is hard to not use them.

Comment: @Pshemo : Without use meaning I want to have a call from Jsp and Java(only),just wanted to understand is this concept possible. Or is it a rule that a call from Jsp has to go via servlet and then Java class

Comment: Call from JSP is in reality call from servlet (since JSP is nicer servlet). You can add some code in JSP which will invoke some methods with little help of scriptlets `<% ... %>` but [you should avoid it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files). About point 2 I am not sure what you want to achieve since running servlets (and JSP) is servers job.

Comment: @Pshemo: Thanks for the explanation and helping to understand the concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a typical main() method has return type `void`, this cannot be done:

```
public staic void main(String[] args) { ... }
```

But you call any static method on that class and return a String and output that to your JSP:

**Class**

```
public class Util {
  public static String doSomething() {
    // do something and generate a String
    return "helloWord";
  }
}
```

**JSP**:

```
<%= Util.doSomething() %>
```

this prints out the return value of your static `doSomething()` method at where the JSP output tag is included.

Comment: thanks for the explanation and giving me clear cut view for the concept

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to call a Java class with main() in JSP and print the value in console or JSP page (without use of a Servlet class)?
>
> Similarly print the value in JSP page from Java class with main() (without use of a Servlet class)?

Any hack is possible, but `Servlet`, `JSP`, and `JSTL` is best suited here

[Checkout tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)